# Socket.io client flooding polling requests on webpack-dev-server, works fine on react-scripts

Tags: java, reactjs, webpack, socket.io, webpack-hmr

I currently have a socket.io server for java connecting to two different socket.io client applications.  One is running on react-scripts and another is on webpack-dev-server.  The socket connection works on both, but on the webpack-dev-server it sends about 100 polling packets a second after connecting.  I am thinking it has something to do with the hot reload, although it happens on a fresh page.  It's confirmed that the server and both clients are all running the same version of socket.io (4.4.1).  I tried setting the transports to websocket to avoid the polling messages but it will not connect. On the react-scripts app it just sends a few polling packets and upgrades the connection without setting transports.  Every polling request always returns a response of 6 on the webpack-dev-server if that helps.  Any ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: hi, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47432256/socket-io-flood-server-with-polling-requests

Comment: Yeah I stated I tried that solution of changing the transports and the socket would not even connect after.  I did a lot of searching before I posted this.